# How to normalize the data correctly in spam dataset

Tags: python, dataset, normalization

- I'm working on the [spam dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/spambase) to classify the inputs into binary classes.
- My problem is that the observations in the dataset are float small numbers in the first 53 columns, and the 54 is float larger numbers, while the last two columns are integers.

#### My Question:

How to Normalize this [dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/spambase/spambase.data)
correctly, so all the observations have the same importance?

```
import pandas as pd
spam = pd.read_table("spambase.data",sep=',',header=None)
```

- one proposed approach which didn't seem very convenient to me, because it normalizes the whole row input is that:

```py
#========================
# Normalization Function
#========================
def Normalize(x):
    '''
    ==================================
    Normalization Function
    ==================================
    -----------
    Parameters:
    -----------
    @Parameter x: Vector
    ---------
    Returns:
    ---------
    Normalized Vector.
    ================================
    '''
    norm=0.0
    for e in x:
        norm+=e**2
    for i in range(len(x)):
        x[i]/=sqrt(norm)
    return x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalizing so that "*all the observations have the same importance*" is kinda ambiguous and ill-defined. In any case, it would be strongly advised to avoid re-inventing the wheel, and use one of the several scalers available out there (e.g. in the [`sklearn.preprocessing`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing) module).

Here is an example using `MinMaxScaler`, which will re-scale your data in [0, 1] *column-wise*:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("spambase.data", header=None)
print(df.head())
# result:
     0     1     2    3     4     5   ...     52     53     54   55    56  57
0  0.00  0.64  0.64  0.0  0.32  0.00  ...  0.000  0.000  3.756   61   278   1
1  0.21  0.28  0.50  0.0  0.14  0.28  ...  0.180  0.048  5.114  101  1028   1
2  0.06  0.00  0.71  0.0  1.23  0.19  ...  0.184  0.010  9.821  485  2259   1
3  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.63  0.00  ...  0.000  0.000  3.537   40   191   1
4  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.63  0.00  ...  0.000  0.000  3.537   40   191   1

[5 rows x 58 columns]

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc = MinMaxScaler() # define the scaler
df_scaled = pd.DataFrame(sc.fit_transform(df)) # fit & transform the data
print(df_scaled.head())
# result:
         0         1         2    3   ...        54        55        56   57
0  0.000000  0.044818  0.125490  0.0  ...  0.002502  0.006007  0.017487  1.0
1  0.046256  0.019608  0.098039  0.0  ...  0.003735  0.010012  0.064836  1.0
2  0.013216  0.000000  0.139216  0.0  ...  0.008008  0.048458  0.142551  1.0
3  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  ...  0.002303  0.003905  0.011995  1.0
4  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  ...  0.002303  0.003905  0.011995  1.0

[5 rows x 58 columns]
```

Keep in mind that normalization depends also from your choice of a model to use: it is practically necessary for neural networks and k-nn (and for k-means clustering), but is is completely redundant for decision trees and tree-ensemble models (Random Forest, GBM etc).